# modifyEntrySources hook with reverse relations

Tags: relations, elementcriteriamodel, entrymodel, craft2

Is it possible to do a reverse relation query in a custom entry source?

https://docs.craftcms.com/v2/plugins/hooks-reference.html#modifyentrysources

I have two entry sections, one called courses and one called course occurrences. Course occurrences are linked via an entries field called `parentCourse`. It easy enough to query course occurrences that don't have a parent course (check if `parentCourse` is empty/not empty, but the reverse seems to be a little more complex.

I'm looking for the ability to have a custom entry source that lists all the parent course records that *don't* have a child record basically, making it a reverse relation.

I tested the [Reverse Relations](https://github.com/boboldehampsink/reverserelations) plugin and it does display the children entries related on the parent so the relation works, but I was wondering if it can be done directly through a criteria query in the `modifyEntrySource` hook?